# To finish the function scrollingText(word)

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program where I want the following result:

[ 'ROBOT',
'OBOTR',
'BOTRO',
'OTROB',
'TROBO' ]

Now I have:

[ 'robotr', 'obotr', 'botr', 'otr', 'tr' ]

Where am I going wrong? Here is my code:

```js
function scrollingText(word) {
  word = word.toUpperCase();
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    arr.push(word[i] + word.slice(i + 1) + word[0]);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(scrollingText('robot'));
```

Comment: use `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: i added to my code now. But the problam somewhere here  arr.push(word[i] + word.slice(i+1) + word[0] );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `word` in each iteration, and not merely `slice` the same `word` repeatedly. Here is my snippet:

```js
function scrollingText(word) {
  let arr = [word.toUpperCase()]; // storing original word
  let wordLength = word.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < wordLength - 1; i++) { // iterating for one less than the string length, in this case, from 0 to 3
    word = word.slice(1) + word[0] // <<-- update word in every iteration
    arr.push(word.toUpperCase());
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(scrollingText('robot'));
```